# How to search a record with special character(') in DB

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to select a row where the matching condition is What's.

How to write the Query?

I can't write like - "SELECT * FROM  WHERE [TITLE] LIKE 'What's'..

What to do ?

Answer (score 11):

Try escaping the quote (') with another quote.

```
declare @FISH TABLE (
    Name varchar(20)
)

insert into @FISH values ('COD''N''CHIPS')
insert into @FISH values ('CODNCHIPS')
SELECT * FROM FISH WHERE [Name] LIKE 'COD''N''CHIPS'
```

Prints out

```
COD'N'CHIPS
```

As expected.